# How do you import .data and .lisp files from the UCI Machine Learning Repository?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the [link](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/credit-screening/) to the data I want to import. The files are .data, .names, and .lisp. How do you import them into Python as a data frame? I have tried:

```
df = pd.read_table('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/credit-screening/crx.data', sep='')
```

As well as `pd.read_csv()` but it doesn't work since the files are not CSV. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the separator when using [`read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html). In this case, your columns are separated by `,`. You should also set `header=None` since the [data file](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/credit-screening/crx.data) does not contain headers (column names). Although `read_table` might work, it is now deprecated so you can use [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) instead.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/credit-screening/crx.data', 
    sep=',', 
    header=None
)

print(df)

     0      1       2  3  4   5   6       7  8  9   10 11 12     13     14 15
0    b  30.83   0.000  u  g   w   v   1.250  t  t   1  f  g  00202      0  +
1    a  58.67   4.460  u  g   q   h   3.040  t  t   6  f  g  00043    560  +
2    a  24.50   0.500  u  g   q   h   1.500  t  f   0  f  g  00280    824  +
3    b  27.83   1.540  u  g   w   v   3.750  t  t   5  t  g  00100      3  +
4    b  20.17   5.625  u  g   w   v   1.710  t  f   0  f  s  00120      0  +
5    b  32.08   4.000  u  g   m   v   2.500  t  f   0  t  g  00360      0  +
6    b  33.17   1.040  u  g   r   h   6.500  t  f   0  t  g  00164  31285  +
7    a  22.92  11.585  u  g  cc   v   0.040  t  f   0  f  g  00080   1349  +
...
[690 rows x 16 columns]
```